# Compiling a conditional alert message based on various selections made in drop down boxes

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

How can I make a function to check and see if a single or combination of selections has been made in any of the 3 boxes and alert me back with any of the resultant combination of messages below:

if a single selection has been made in any of the 3 dropdown boxes: "searching the database by [selectbox] only"

if a selection has been made in any 2 drop down boxes "searching the database by  [selectbox] and  [selectbox]

if a selection has been made in all 3 drop down boxes "searching the database by  [selectbox],  [selectbox], and  [selectbox]

here is the setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
Firtsname (x)<br>
    <select id="firstname">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="John">John</option>
        <option value="Jacob">Jacob</option>
        <option value="Nancy">Nancy</option>
        <option value="Loretta">Loretta</option>
    </select>
<br>
Lastname (y)<br>
    <select id="lastnname">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Pearson">Pearson</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Scott">Scott</option>
        <option value="Murray">Murray</option>
    </select>
    <br>
Age (z)<br>
    <select id="age">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="39">39</option>
    </select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="testit">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Read Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val();
```

To Set Select Option Value

```
$('#selectId').val('newValue');
```

To Read Selected Text

```
$('#selectId>option:selected').text();
```

In the #selectId, put your html element's id and you should be fine!